# Retrieve a single element from reducer array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a company reducer that I'd want to contain an array of companies. Since each object is fairly large when user goes on `/company/name` I only want to fetch that one object from my API and add it to this array, so if user visits the same company page multiple times I won't have to call again the api.

My reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  companies: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_COMPANIES:
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case GET_COMPANY:
      return {
        ...state,
        companies: [action.payload, ...state.companies]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Is there a way for me to update the state in reducer and just return 1 company? Like shown above this would return all companies in this state, though logically it does not make sense with 'GET_COMPANY'

My action:

```
export const getCompany = name => dispatch => {
  axios.get("/companies/" + name).then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: GET_COMPANY,
      payload: res.data
    })
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some 'id' or 'name' or other property of the company object you want to retrieve,
and than you can use find method to do this:

```
action.payload.find(company=>company.id===id)
```

According to the MDN:
The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find